# How to build a REACT Native app automatically using GitLab

Tags: android, ios, react-native, continuous-integration, apk

I am looking for a way to build the APK of my React Native App automatically using a GitLab pipeline, I can't seem to find a solution on the web that does not use Expo, do you have any ideas on how to do this?

We have a team of testers who would like to test the APK on a real device, do you have any idea on how to achieve this (without Expo)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey I've successfully automated react native build apps using gitlab CI/CD pipelines.
**You need to create ".gitlab-ci.yml" fil**e **in the root of your project and add below scripts** and **may change as per your needs**.

```
before_script:
  - yarn install --frozen-lockfile #--frozen-lockfile to make sure we will have the same packages version

stages:
  - build

build project:
  stage: build
  image: reactnativecommunity/react-native-android
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - yarn.lock
    paths:
      - node_modules
    policy: pull #`pull` the jobs pull the cache at the beginning but do not push the changes again.
  script:
    - yarn build:apk # is the scripts defined in your package.json as "cd android #&& ./gradlew assembleRelease"
    - yarn install --pure-lockfile --cache-folder .yarn
    
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

*let me know if you have any problems*

Comment: It gives me an error: Command "build:apk" not found. Did you come across this issue? 
I tried using npm too but throws an error nom command not found.

Comment: @Krunal script: yarn build: android is the script defined in your root package.json i.e you need to define in scripts as "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease"